Creating empty scene in panda3d
I am new to panda3d library for 3d rendering. In all their tutorials, they begin with creating a scene by loading a model with lines like these

self.scene = self.loader.loadModel("models/environment")

self.scene.reparentTo(self.render)

which load models/environment.egg  file.
There's plenty of models available, however, I haven't found any solution to create just blank scene with only white background on it. I have tried passing loadModel method no arguments but that didn't work.
Is there any possibility to do so or we always have to load some model?
